# Server 2012 stopped accepting computers joining to our domain with error 53: the network path was not found

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2012, ldap, domain-controller

We have **Windows Server 2012 R2 Standard** as our DC. Several workstations were added to our domain successfully.

But then (I cannot determine what exactly could be a show-stopper) it stopped accepting new nodes joining the domain.

Nodes are different (OS also different: Win 10 Ent, Win 7 Pro, Debian Wheezy), but the problem is more or less the same: at some point of the procedure a workstation requests something on DC and gets "**the network path was not found**" error 53 (0x35).

I tried dcdiag, dnslint, PortQry for diagnostics. They do not find a problem (I can supply their reports). Switching firewalls and antivirus software off both on server and workstation does not help. The ms-DS-MachineAccountQuota parameter is extended to 255. LDAP is accessible. DNS records were checked many times (though maybe I miss something important there). I also receive the same error 53 if I try to address some shared domain resource from outside, even if I supply valid credentials.

NetworkProvider\Order key is correct. DNS and WINS server addresses are properly assigned on both server and workstations (IPv4 of the server). NetBIOS over TCP/IP enabled.

DC is not on the LAN but in a datacenter.

**Any idea what happens?
Where to look further?**

Below I supply excerpts from netsetup.log - first, of the workstation which successfully joined our domain some time ago. Then, an excerpt from netsetup.log of a node which fails to join it:

1. success:

```
07/28/2015 14:08:17:791 NetpGetLsaPrimaryDomain: status: 0x0  
07/28/2015 14:08:17:791 NetpMachineValidToJoin: status: 0x0  
07/28/2015 14:08:17:791 NetpJoinDomain 
07/28/2015 14:08:17:791 HostName: Fontanka-win81
07/28/2015 14:08:17:791 NetbiosName: FONTANKA-WIN81
07/28/2015 14:08:17:791 Domain: OUR.DNS.DOMAIN
07/28/2015 14:08:17:791 MachineAccountOU: (NULL)
07/28/2015 14:08:17:791 Account: OUR_NETBIOS_DOMAIN\account
07/28/2015 14:08:17:791 Options: 0x23
07/28/2015 14:08:17:791 NetpLoadParameters: loading registry parameters...
07/28/2015 14:08:17:791 NetpLoadParameters: DNSNameResolutionRequired not found, defaulting to '1' 0x2
07/28/2015 14:08:17:791 NetpLoadParameters: DomainCompatibilityMode not found, defaulting to '0' 0x2
07/28/2015 14:08:17:791 NetpLoadParameters: status: 0x2
07/28/2015 14:08:17:791 NetpValidateName: checking to see if 'OUR.DNS.DOMAIN' is valid as type 3 name
07/28/2015 14:08:17:791 NetpValidateName: OUR.DNS.DOMAIN' is not a valid NetBIOS domain name: 0x7b
07/28/2015 14:08:18:119 NetpCheckDomainNameIsValid [ Exists ] for 'OUR.DNS.DOMAIN' returned 0x0
07/28/2015 14:08:18:119 NetpValidateName: name 'OUR.DNS.DOMAIN' is valid for type 3
07/28/2015 14:08:18:119 NetpDsGetDcName: trying to find DC in domain 'OUR.DNS.DOMAIN', flags: 0x40001010
07/28/2015 14:08:18:728 NetpDsGetDcName: failed to find a DC having account 'FONTANKA-WIN81$': 0x525, last error is 0x0
07/28/2015 14:08:18:898 NetpLoadParameters: loading registry parameters...
07/28/2015 14:08:18:898 NetpLoadParameters: DNSNameResolutionRequired not found, defaulting to '1' 0x2
07/28/2015 14:08:18:898 NetpLoadParameters: DomainCompatibilityMode not found, defaulting to '0' 0x2
07/28/2015 14:08:18:898 NetpLoadParameters: status: 0x2
07/28/2015 14:08:19:030 NetpDsGetDcName: status of verifying DNS A record name resolution for 'dc.in.our.domain': 0x0
07/28/2015 14:08:19:030 NetpDsGetDcName: found DC '\\dc.in.our.domain' in the specified domain
07/28/2015 14:08:19:030 NetpJoinDomainOnDs: NetpDsGetDcName returned: 0x0
07/28/2015 14:08:19:030 NetpDisableIDNEncoding: using FQDN our.dns.domain from dcinfo
07/28/2015 14:08:19:033 NetpDisableIDNEncoding: DnsDisableIdnEncoding(UNTILREBOOT) on 'our.dns.domain' succeeded
07/28/2015 14:08:19:034 NetpJoinDomainOnDs: NetpDisableIDNEncoding returned: 0x0
07/28/2015 14:08:24:013 NetpJoinDomainOnDs: status of connecting to dc '\\dc.in.our.domain': 0x0
07/28/2015 14:08:24:013 NetpGetDnsHostName: PrimaryDnsSuffix defaulted to DNS domain name: our.dns.domain
07/28/2015 14:08:24:201 NetpProvisionComputerAccount:
07/28/2015 14:08:24:201 lpDomain: OUR.DNS.DOMAIN
07/28/2015 14:08:24:201 lpHostName: Fontanka-win81
07/28/2015 14:08:24:201 lpMachineAccountOU: (NULL)
07/28/2015 14:08:24:201 lpDcName: dc.in.our.domain
07/28/2015 14:08:24:201 lpMachinePassword: (null)
07/28/2015 14:08:24:201 lpAccount: OUR_NETBIOS_DOMAIN\account
07/28/2015 14:08:24:201 lpPassword: (non-null)
07/28/2015 14:08:24:201 dwJoinOptions: 0x23
07/28/2015 14:08:24:201 dwOptions: 0x40000003
07/28/2015 14:08:24:904 NetpLdapBind: Verified minimum encryption strength on dc.in.our.domain: 0x0
..........
```

2. failure:

```
04/20/2016 20:44:37:251 NetpDoDomainJoin
04/20/2016 20:44:37:251 NetpDoDomainJoin: using current computer names
04/20/2016 20:44:37:251 NetpDoDomainJoin: NetpGetComputerNameEx(NetBios) returned 0x0
04/20/2016 20:44:37:251 NetpDoDomainJoin: NetpGetComputerNameEx(DnsHostName) returned 0x0
04/20/2016 20:44:37:311 NetpMachineValidToJoin: 'ARMIDE'
04/20/2016 20:44:37:350 NetpMachineValidToJoin: status: 0x0
04/20/2016 20:44:37:365 NetpJoinDomain
04/20/2016 20:44:37:365 HostName: ARMIDE
04/20/2016 20:44:37:365 NetbiosName: ARMIDE
04/20/2016 20:44:37:365 Domain: OUR.DNS.DOMAIN
04/20/2016 20:44:37:365 MachineAccountOU: (NULL)
04/20/2016 20:44:37:365 Account: OUR.DNS.DOMAIN\account
04/20/2016 20:44:37:365 Options: 0x23
04/20/2016 20:44:37:432 NetpValidateName: checking to see if 'OUR.DNS.DOMAIN' is valid as type 3 name
04/20/2016 20:44:37:432 NetpValidateName: 'OUR.DNS.DOMAIN' is not a valid NetBIOS domain name: 0x7b
04/20/2016 20:44:37:713 NetpCheckDomainNameIsValid [ Exists ] for 'OUR.DNS.DOMAIN' returned 0x0
04/20/2016 20:44:37:713 NetpValidateName: name 'OUR.DNS.DOMAIN' is valid for type 3
04/20/2016 20:44:37:713 NetpDsGetDcName: trying to find DC in domain 'OUR.DNS.DOMAIN', flags: 0x40001010
04/20/2016 20:44:38:313 NetpDsGetDcName: failed to find a DC having account 'ARMIDE$': 0x525, last error is 0x0
04/20/2016 20:44:38:475 NetpDsGetDcName: status of verifying DNS A record name resolution for 'dc.in.our.domain': 0x0
04/20/2016 20:44:38:475 NetpDsGetDcName: found DC '\\dc.in.our.domain' in the specified domain
04/20/2016 20:44:38:475 NetpJoinDomainOnDs: NetpDsGetDcName returned: 0x0
04/20/2016 20:44:38:475 NetpDisableIDNEncoding: using FQDN our.dns.domain from dcinfo
04/20/2016 20:44:38:546 NetpDisableIDNEncoding: DnsDisableIdnEncoding(UNTILREBOOT) on 'our.dns.domain' succeeded
04/20/2016 20:44:38:546 NetpJoinDomainOnDs: NetpDisableIDNEncoding returned: 0x0
04/20/2016 20:45:43:580 NetUseAdd to \\dc.in.our.domain\IPC$ returned 53
04/20/2016 20:45:43:580 NetpJoinDomainOnDs: status of connecting to dc '\\dc.in.our.domain': 0x35
04/20/2016 20:45:43:580 NetpJoinDomainOnDs: Function exits with status of: 0x35
04/20/2016 20:45:43:582 NetpResetIDNEncoding: DnsDisableIdnEncoding(RESETALL) on 'our.dns.domain' returned 0x0
04/20/2016 20:45:43:587 NetpJoinDomainOnDs: NetpResetIDNEncoding on 'our.dns.domain': 0x0
04/20/2016 20:45:43:587 NetpDoDomainJoin: status: 0x35
```

Note that in the success log IPC$ was not requested at all.

Comment: Run the AD BPA on the server to ensure that's happy. Are all the network subnets included in AD sites? Are clients picking up correct and sane info from DHCP?

Comment: Subnet and sites: DC is a standalone server located in some datacenter. Workstations are distributed around the globe. I know I should set up VPN and local DHCP, but first I wanted to fix this problem. And despite the fact that yes, it is bad to run a standalone DC w/o VPN, but it worked before.

Comment: So you're connecting across the "live internet" to a DC in a datacenter and *not* via a VPN? To be honest, I think the real question isn't "why isn't it working now" but "how the hell did it *ever* work"? My first thought is that if the datacentre wasn't already firewalling the ports used by AD clients, someone noticed the traffic, realised that their network config is bad and that they should feel bad, and updated their config.All the info I'm aware of about the error codes you're seeing points to a network issue.

Comment: AD BPA: it gave me some warnings and even errors, from first glance nothing critical, but I'm working on solving them now, get back with report when done.

Comment: Well, maybe you're right, and they just started to block AD traffic recently... So the sequence you propose is 1. fine-tune VPN, 2. set up and running local DHCP (or just IP pool), 3. get all wksts to VPN and make sure everything works, 4. firewall on DC: close all ports but VPN for public, current config inside domain, 5. maybe smth more, 6. try to join new wksts from within VPS, right?

Comment: I wouldn't worry about the DHCP so much for now for testing, but I'd try creating a VPN, getting workstations joined to the VPN with a static address maybe (unless DHCP is easier to configure for you) then testing again when the workstations are on the same LAN segment, via VPN, as the DC. And yes, firewall off anything that doesn't need to be exposed to the Internet - no sense in borrowing trouble.

Comment: I've installed RRAS as a VPN server. Is it right that PPTP is completely not suitable in my case or it still should work, and is L2TP the best choice?

Comment: PPTP is not secure. This sounds like a scenario for AzureAD, not trying to VPN multiple sites around the globe to your one datacenter.

Answer (score 1):

You can also check:

- Anti-Virus "End point security" which may hinder traffic to the IPC$ share (try removing this on a client machine you like to join)
- Ensure your DC is not multi-homed (e.g. make sure only one NIC, and one NIC only, is connected/active/live)

HTH.